# How to translate symfony dropbox choices in the formtype

Tags: php, symfony, translation, symfony-forms, multilingual

In the form generated by Symfony I would like to translate the child options, how can this be done?

```
        ->add('business', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array('Zakelijk' => true, 'Prive' => false),
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'choices_as_values' => true,
        ))
```

I tried to include the standard symfony translation code directly in the code above, but then i get a php error.

```
$this->get('translator')->trans('business');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`words.en.yml`

```
Zakelijk: Zakelijk
Prive: Prive
```

In your form:

```
'translation_domain' => 'fooo'

'choices' => array('Zakelijk' => true, 'Prive' => false),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use translations. In your bundle you need to create in Resources/Translations with format i18N and one extension (yml or php or xliff). In your form use for example "app.form.zalelijk" with yaml format.

```
        'choices' => array('app.form.zakelijk' => true, 'app.form.prive' => false)
```

Twig will translate the string in your request locale to render the form.